# Display .RDLC report embedded in a DLL file

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, embedded-resource

I have a report that is used by a windows service and a form application.  So, I want to put embed the report in a DLL file that can be used by both.

The problem is that if I try to set the ReportEmbeddedResource property of a ReportViewer control in my windows form app, it will search the windows form app for the resource, not the dll file.

e.g.: Code from the windows form app:

```
rv.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MyReportInMyDLLFile.rdlc"
```

How can I make the above command look for the embedded resource in my DLL file?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Reports.dll");
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Reports.MyReport.rdlc");
reportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);
```

Comment: When i use above code in `application page` in SharePoint 2010, following error raised:`Could not load file or assembly 'file:///c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Reports.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`, but it works in WinForm Applications.

Comment: Such an old answer.. but works just as well as it does today! I followed the answers below.. where I have a report in another assembly within two folders, and it simply did not work, and yes it was an embedded resource. I copied and pasted it into the second line of this answer, and it worked!

Comment: can this method work when I am getting the reports from a signed `.exe` instead of a `dll`?

Comment: Worked great after I set LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = null.  Same with LocalReport.ReportPath.  If not set to null when loading through a stream it will attempt to load the resource with either ReportEmbeddedResource or ReportPath.

Answer (score 23):

Just use the full namespace of the assembly, then folder names and then the name of the file:

```
rv.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = 
    "My.Assembly.Namespace.Folder1.Folder2.MyReport.rdlc";
```

Then make sure the report file is set as an embedded resource using the properties pane.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, but I guess this only works if the report is in the same assembly where this code is.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez you are right: the report can read the embedded RDLC only in the same assembly, otherwise will throw an exception "There is no definitions with name MyNamespace.MyReport.rdlc"

Answer (score 12):

Probably the best thing to do would be to get a stream to the RDLC resource from the other assembly, then pass that to the "LoadReportDefinition" method of the Report Viewer control.

Details of how to get a stream from an embedded resource in a different assembly can be found here : [Retrieving Resources with the ResourceManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408(VS.71).aspx)

Additionally, you will need to refer to the embedded resource using it's full namespace path.

E.g. if you have an application with a default namespace of **TheApp**, and you keep a report called "**MyReport.rdlc**" in a folder called "**Reports**", the report reference call would be:-

```
rv.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "TheApp.Reports.MyReport.rdlc";
```