# SSRS report expressions not being evaluated when inside an MVC3 IIS6 C# project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services, iis-6, incompatibility

In my MVC3 project I wanted to add reports, so I used SSRS local report rdlc (Microsoft Reporting) by creating a sub folder and putting the .aspx web viewer and rdlc in it.  All was well until I tried expressions that had any sort of script functions in.  They were not being evaluated and returning #Error (Even simple things like Len etc) wherever in the report I put them (header, body footer etc).

I am using an objectDatasource returning int values, Server 2003 SP2(hence IIS6) and vs2010 SP1 (Required by MVC3 package deployment).

So far I have worked out that

1) If I create a standard WEB project(NOT MVC3), then the expressions are evaluated.

2) If I use an MVC3 website on Server2008 (IIS7) then that works

I suspect that the IIS wildcard and gumph required to get MVC3 working with IIS6 is to blame, and am wondering if anyone else can shed light on this

Comment: Point (2) is interesting. Are there any clues in the `<system.web>` section (e.g. referenced DLLs) that could usefully be copied over to `<system.webServer>` on the IIS6 side?

Comment: Found another article claiming that ssrs and mvc are not always happy together http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672304/visual-studio-2010-local-ssrs-report-rdlc-with-object-data-source in the UPDATE section, it claims that you cannot use objectDataSource within mvc.  So they set up another website, same as me. Hmm

Comment: Ah Jeremy, Slowest comment response ever.  I did have a whizz through the config and could not see anything ssrs related.  Because the MVC3 and IIS6 combination is pretty unlikely (most will be on iis7), most people will not have a problem with this, so its probably going to rot.

Comment: Yeah, you got it. This is actually a duplicate...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 - SSRS Report (rdlc) and Business Object Data Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087818/mvc3-ssrs-report-rdlc-and-business-object-data-source)