# MVC3 - SSRS Report (rdlc) and Business Object Data Source

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services, rdlc, business-objects

I am trying to prototype the use of Sql Reporting Services (rdlc) files in my MVC3 app in Visual Studio 2010, and I am able to create my data access layer, add my report and bind it to my business objects just fine in MVC2 and asp.net forms projects.

When I try to duplicate this in an MVC3 app, I can't bind my report to the business objects, it doesn't even give me any option.  Instead it wants to create a data source to the database.  What is the issue here, any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. The solution is to add on aspx page to the solution. credit goes to [Can't see or add Website Data Sources in RDLC report in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923569/cant-see-or-add-website-data-sources-in-rdlc-report-in-asp-net-mvc) for the solution.

Comment: Damn! Here is a good way to screw your productivity... thanks guys!