# generate Microsoft Report with LINQ in MVC 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq, reporting

I am developing an asp.net MVC 2 app in which I am going to implement the Microsoft reports. The problem is this how can i bind the LINQ returning object with the parameters of reports. According to my knowledge I can bind the parameter with the data set but I don't know how to bind it with LINQ. Moreover, I am new in this field so please give me link of Microsoft Reports tutorial with LINQ.

Comment: Simple google search returned http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-PWu5DoOC0

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Reports uses aspx pages.  I had problems with these working within an MVC3 site, and so have to create another web application for the reports (that used the same business logic as the main site).

It would be best to use the objectDataSource for the report, and create it within the aspx page.  In that way you can intercept the pages querystring (or post) parameters, and used them in the constructor of the method used to create the objectDataSource data.

Details about the MVC problems are here [Visual Studio 2010 Local SSRS Report (.rdlc) with Object Data Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672304/visual-studio-2010-local-ssrs-report-rdlc-with-object-data-source)